# Multiple sliders on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello everyone I'm using this plugin http://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Fullscreen-Horizontal-Page-Slider-with-jQuery-CSS3-HSlider.html and I want to have more than one slider on single page. Here is my code:

```
        height = $( window ).height() - 98;
    transalte = (height/2);
    $.each($('.gallery section'),function(i){
        $(this).css({
            position:"absolute",
            width:"100%",
            height: height+'px',
            left:i*100 +"%"
        }).addClass("section").attr("data-index", i+1);
        $(this).find(".img").css({
            minWidth: "100%",
            minHeight: "100%",
            position:"absolute",
            zIndex:5
        })
        $(this).find("article").css({
            position:"absolute",
            width:"100%",
            height: '100%',
            bottom:0,
            padding:42,
            zIndex:6,
            'transform':'translateY(-'+(height+10)+'px)',
            'color': 'white',
        })
    });


    <div class="gallery">
        <div class="slider">
            <section>
              <div class="img" style="background: url('images/london2.jpeg') no-repeat; background-size: cover;"></div>


            </section>
        </div>
    </div><!--end gallery -->

<div class="gallery">
        <div class="slider">
            <section>
              <div class="img" style="background: url('images/london2.jpeg') no-repeat; background-size: cover;"></div>


            </section>
        </div>


    </div><!--end gallery -->
```

I tried to reset i in each function but it doesn't works properly. It adds next data-index to section in another gallery. Is there any way to make multiple sliders using this plugin?

Comment: If you don't mind changing to another plugin, [fullpage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) allows exactly that. Multiple sliders, all of them full screen.

Answer (score 0):

What is it exactly you want to accomplish? By looking at the [demo](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Fullscreen-Horizontal-Page-Slider-with-jQuery-CSS3-HSlider/) and your question, it seems to me that you want to add multiple slides (images) to one gallery.

In this case, move all of your `<section>` into one wrapping `<div>` and initialize the plugin as shown on the page.

```
$(".slider").HSlider();
```

Does this help?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It just add slider to one gallery.